# request.getAttribute() gives only null

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, web

I'm using two combo boxes,

`onee` and `twoo` that get values from the database. The selected value is to be stored in database.

code for `setAttribute`:

```
<% String s1=""; %>
<select id="onee" name="onee" style="margin-left:400px" required="">
   <%  while(rs.next()){ %>
   <option id="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" name="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
   <% } %>
</select>
<% s1=request.getParameter("onee");%>
<% request.setAttribute("s1",s1);%>
<%String s2=""; %>
<select name="twoo" id="twoo" style="margin-left:200px" required="">
   <%  while(rss.next()){ %>
   <option id="<%=rss.getString(1)%>" name="<%=rss.getString(1)%>" value="<%=rss.getString(1)%>"><%=rss.getString(1)%></option>
   <% } %>
</select>
<% s2=request.getParameter("twoo");%>
<% request.setAttribute("s2",s2);%>
```

code for `getAttribute`:

```
String oone=(String)request.getAttribute("s1");
String ttwo=(String)request.getAttribute("s2");
```

The query:

```
String sql="insert into choices(ID,One,Two) values ('" + oone + "','" + ttwo + "')";
```

It only stores `null` and `null`

Comment: It's not the problem, but **please** don't do that in production code. That code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. More: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: http://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc#a827434

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. First you declare a String with new()?!

`<%String s2=new String(); %>`

And then you set it to some value from the request?

```
<% s2=request.getParameter("twoo");%>
```

After that you set it at the request, and wonder why it is null?

```
<% request.setAttribute("s2",s2);%>
```

Consider a redesign of your code